# Is the complex tangent function bounded?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I was given the task to analyze the complex tangent function, and I am a bit conflicted on some of the function's properties.

The question I was unable to answer is the following:

**"Does the function $\tan(z)$ have a local min point/local max point?"**

I know that $\sin(z)$ and $\cos(z)$ are not bounded, and therefore I assumed that $\tan(z)$ is not bounded as a result but wasn't sure of it

I was hoping to find a way to prove this claim (If indeed it's correct!)
Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: 1. The restriction of the complex tangent to the real axis is...? 2. What do you mean by _a local min/max point_ of a complex-valued function?

Comment: Cf. [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis))